# What is the difference from a theorem and a meta-theorem?

Tags: logic, terminology, meta-math

I'm confused about what a meta-theorem exactly is and if a meta-theorem can be used to prove a theorem. To illustrate my confusion i give an example.

Given the three statements:

1. Every vector space has a Hamel basis.
2. If a statement in ZFC cannot be proved without AC then this statement is not constructive.
3. In infinite dimensional vector spaces is generally impossible to construct the elements of a Hamel basis.

I think that all agree that 1) is a theorem in ZFC.
I suppose that 2) is a metatheorem about ZFC (but I don't know the proof). 
Since 3) is a consequence of 1) and 2) is it a theorem or a meta-theorem?

Comment: It seems to me that 2) is not the correct example, becuse "constructive" is not a *formal* concept (it is not "precise")...

Comment: Do you know the difference between a statement and a meta-statement?

Comment: Consider *propositional logic* as a formal mathematical theory; it has axioms and rules of infeence. A theorem of prop log (in a "typical" axiomatization of it) is : $p \rightarrow p$; we prove it through a derivation from axioms. The "paradigmatic case" of metatheorem for this theory is the *Deduction Th* : it states that from a formal proof (a derivation in the propositional calculus) of formula $A$ under assumption $B$ (i.e. $B \vdash A$) we can build a new derivation of $B \rightarrow A$.

Comment: @Git Gud maybe I don't well understand that difference... can you explain in brief?

Comment: @EmilioNovati Knowing the difference should dissipate your doubts, but knowing the answer should explain the difference too. The latter has be done by Mauro in his comment above and by Asaf in his answer below, so I'll assume it will suffice.

Comment: You can see some good discussions in Kenneth Kunen, [The Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=_B_oQQAACAAJ) (2009), page 28 or George Tourlakis, [Lectures in Logic and Set Theory : Volume 1 Mathematical Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=rzCBnQEACAAJ) (2003), page 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theorems are things proved from a theory. Meta-theorems are things proved *about* the theory.

The statement:

> If $\sf ZF$ is consistent, then $\sf ZF$ does not prove $\sf AC$.

Is a meta-theorem about the theory $\sf ZF$. It quantifies over all proofs that we can write from the axioms of $\sf ZF$. If you like to think about it semantically, proofs are not objects of the universe of $\sf ZF$, sets are. We can represent proofs as sets, and we can show that this representation is somewhat faithful to the source; but proofs from $\sf ZF$ are not objects of the model of $\sf ZF$ we work with.

On the other hand,

> $\sf ZF$ proves that the axiom of choice is equivalent to the statement "Every vector space has a basis".

Is a theorem, cleverly disguised as a meta-theorem. It might talk about provability from $\sf ZF$, but really what we say is that there is a proof from $\sf ZF$ that the axiom of choice is equivalent to some other statement. We are not *really* interested in the meta-theory here, we are not interested in the proof that there exists a proof. We just write the proof down and check that it is a valid proof.

So you need to separate what is in the theory, what are the objects that the theory is concerned with; and what is in the meta-theory, which are statement about the theory, about proofs, etc.

---

Finally, let me remark, that "something is not constructive" is not a well-defined notion. There are different interpretation for the term "constructive", one of which is by definition "something provable without the axiom of choice".

So since "constructive" has no concrete meaning, it's not quite in the meta-theory or in the theory. It's more of a philosophical argument as for the meaning of the term "constructive". (At least until further clarifications.)

Comment: thanks for edit! So the proposition 2) in my question is not a theorem nor a meta-theorem. But it's frequently used, so, what it is?

Comment: It's a statement about mathematics.

Comment: Compare this to "set theory is great!" this is not a theorem, nor a meta-theorem. It's just a statement about mathematics.